# Add text and icon to pushpin image in Bing Maps for Android

Tags: image, text, bing-maps

I have a custom image for the pushpin in Bing Maps for Android. I want to add some text and an icon (png) to this pushpin. The text and icon should be on separate lines. Any help...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control of the contents of an overlay entity on the map, you might want to try an Infobox instead.

Note, that this works for the ajax maps ... if you're using the ajax v7 map control, that should work on Android as well.